# Jquery Datepicker goes away after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, postback

I have a Jquery Datepicker included in a $(document).ready clause.

My problem is when I do a PostBack, it returns the view and my DatePicker stops working. I found many messages related to this problem but they're about web applications in WebForms, so they say that you have to include the declaration of the control in a Page_Load method.
Any ideas how to resolve this in ASP.NET MVC? I'm a beginner and I didn't know so much about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to reinitialize the date picker after the post back. If you reload the page via an Ajax call the page elements won't know about the previous initialization. I include a reinitialization function in my Ajax success handler.